# A person with mental disability

Tags: vocabulary

In the USA and the UK, What is the **acceptable** word for a person who is mentally abnormal? For instance, I've read that 'lunatic' is now considered to be offensive. Which of the following is acceptable in those societies, especially when used in the formal writings?

1. Mentally ill
2. Mentally disabled
3. Intellectually disabled
4. Mentally retarded
5. CP

Answer (score 1):

It's a long, long time since *lunatic* has been anything but a colloquial insult.

You seem to be confused in your definitions. *Mental/psychiatric illness* is an acquired condition which can be treated. (2), (3) and (4) refer to irreversible conditions, usually present from childhood. The approved term, at least in the UK, is  *people with learning difficulties*.

If CP means *cerebral palsy*, that is a physical disability which has nothing to do with intellectual impairment.

Comment: "If CP means cerebral palsy" see my comment about 'spaz' above.

Answer (score -1):

The best term to use at the moment is **disturbed**. It covers a wide range of mental issues, and is not offensive in any way. The [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disturbed) defines it as:

> not thinking or behaving normally because of mental or emotional problems (UK)

> so mentally confused or ill that special treatment is necessary (US)

In my opinion, the US definition would also serve well in the UK.

Comment: "In my opinion, the US definition would also serve well in the UK." Oh dear, no! Too pejorative and judgemental. We can say that someone has 'mental health issues' or 'mental health problems'. You might see 'has been a client of the mental health services'. When speaking respectfully, we don't say that people are crippled, retarded, crazy, mad, deranged, demented, disturbed, etc. Incidentally, a major US/UK difference in this area is that, in the UK, calling someone a 'spaz' if they are clumsy, is one of the worst things you can say.

Comment: In general, we concentrate on the person, not the illness or condition, thus a person with cerebral palsy (NOT 'a spastic'), and a person with a mental health condition, (not 'a lunatic, schizophrenic, depressive', etc).

Comment: In the UK, 'spaz', noun or verb, has the same effect and significance in discussions about disability, and generally, as the N-word would have in discussions about race or in general conversation.

Comment: We don't call people with Down (or Down's) syndrome 'mongols' any more.